# Why am I getting a "Call to member function format() on a non-object" error?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I am trying to add a hook to post saving using WP Frontend User

When the form saves and the post is created within the "save_post" function I am trying to find the value of a custom field "cf_end_date" and assign it to something else

I am not able to grab the custom field "cf_end_date" value fast enough. If I go to the back end and edit an existing post then the function works fine.

Here is my code in functions.php

```
// assign post expiration
function acf_set_expiry($post_id){

            $date = get_post_meta($post_id, 'cf_end_date', true);
    }


//modified update_post_meta function
function expirationdate_update_post_meta_acf($id, $date) {
    // don't run the echo if this is an auto save

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // don't run the echo if the function is called for saving revision.
    $posttype = get_post_type($id);
    if ( $posttype == 'revision' )
    {
        return;
    } else {        
    //'M j, Y' is the format my ACF date field is outputting - can be differ from each setup!
        $formatted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $date);

        $month   = intval($formatted_date->format('m'));
        $day     = intval($formatted_date->format('d'));
        $year    = intval($formatted_date->format('y'));

        //I am not using time in my ACF field, so I am setting it manually to the end of the day.
        $hour    = 23;
        $minute  = 59;

        $opts = array();
        $ts = get_gmt_from_date("$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute:0",'U');

        // Schedule/Update Expiration
        //$opts['expireType'] = 'draft';
        $opts['id'] = $id;

        _scheduleExpiratorEvent($id,$ts,$opts);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'acf_set_expiry',100);
```

Answer (score 1):

“Call to member function format() on a non-object” means that `$formatted_date` is not an object.

Why do you need 2 functions for this? Can't you just check the post meta for your custom field in the save routine? Especially with such a late priority the custom field should already be saved.

```
function acf_set_expiry($post_id) {

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // don't run the echo if the function is called for saving revision.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;


    //'M j, Y' is the format my ACF date field is outputting - can be differ from each setup!

        // get the date in this function
        $date = get_post_meta($post_id, 'cf_end_date', true);

        $formatted_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $date);

        $month   = intval($formatted_date->format('m'));
        $day     = intval($formatted_date->format('d'));
        $year    = intval($formatted_date->format('y'));

        //I am not using time in my ACF field, so I am setting it manually to the end of the day.
        $hour    = 23;
        $minute  = 59;

        $opts = array();
        $ts = get_gmt_from_date("$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute:0",'U');

        // Schedule/Update Expiration
        //$opts['expireType'] = 'draft';
        $opts['id'] = $id;

        _scheduleExpiratorEvent($id,$ts,$opts);

}

add_action('save_post', 'acf_set_expiry',100);
```

I would suggested perhaps adding some conditional checks to see if the `$date` exists before trying to turn it into an object. Additionally you should add permissions checks as seen in the [codex metabox examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Examples).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error, it's as if upon form save the custom field value cannot be extracted. Not sure why it's happening.

Comment: Well I still would add some conditional checks. That way if you don't have a date object you don't try to run the functions on it. You might also consider using the value from the `$_POST` array instead of trying to get the post meta. Again, take a look at the example metabox I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone getting this error on a result which you expect to be datetime object: Check for null values (these dates are often nullable, but null is not an object, and will throw an error because it doesnt have the format() member)